# Aurelia - accessing shared ValueConverter from a view

Tags: aurelia

If I have a value converter 'XyzValueConverter' class exported from 'xvc.js' file in the root directory with a 'toView(value)' method, how do I access/reference that value converter from a view?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to import the converter just like a custom element into the view.

At the top of the view template

```
<template>
    <import from='xvc'></import>
...
    <p>${someValue | xyz}</p>
....
```

Comment: for me <require from='./valueConverters'></require>